# Cannot make calls through Skype

Tags: release-loki, skype, webcam

I've recently installed Skype to my computer, which runs Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki. Even though it was installed smoothly, when I try to click on call icon, it does nothing. So now I'm unable to make any kind of calls, voice or video, through it.

Also in the voice and camera settings section, even though Skype says it detected HD WebCam, the test screen is black and my webcam doesn't turn on. Any ideas what is causing this, or how to fix it?